# Tom Ritter, Ngu Soon Hui what is your secret?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, google

When you [search for 'stackoverflow' on Google](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=stackoverflow), you get the following screen:
[image]

I'm curious what special abilities Tom and Ngu have to get on the Google search? I'd expect the top users to appear there.

Comment: I declare shennanigans!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I have to periodically go through and clean up the sitelinks in Google webmaster tools.

For some reason Google enjoys escalating some user profiles to sitelink level...

Comment: You're just jealous.

Comment: If you want to fix that permanently by having 8 links, I would volunteer to have my account added. No need for compensation, I'm willing to make that sacrifice for the team.

Comment: well for the record my profile was a sitelink on meta and I removed it as well (I went through all the trilogy sites in webmaster tools while I was at it). No nepotism allowed at Stack Overflow!

Comment: @Michel: I'm aware you were just kidding but since not everyone may know this, you can only tell google to not display a certain sitelink; you can't tell google which ones to display.

Comment: Looks like it's happening again, with user "OMG Ponies" and user "Kendal Helmstetter Gelner" http://www.google.com/#hl=en&source=hp&q=stackoverflow&aq=f&aqi=g3g-s1g6&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=CUMSPWd1rTIL_IJXggwTHj_j2BQAAAKoEBU_QZbZL&pbx=1&fp=ea2cd8eab02d18af

Comment: Can we please leave OMG Ponies?

Answer (score 34):

I don't see this. When I google Stack Overflow it just says "Did you mean Jon Skeet?", and the only result is his profile page.

---

Courtesy of @Bobby:

[image: The real Google results if you search for StackOverflow]

Comment: Screenshots or it didn't happen.

Comment: @Aarobot: There you go: http://img256.imageshack.us/i/stackoverflowgoogle.png/

Comment: @Ngu Soon Hui: Then your Google must be broken. ;)

Answer (score 22):

And just for the records, the current sitelinks are really showing a professional side of the site:

[image]

Comment: OMGWTFBBQ ROFLOLMAO

Comment: EPIC WIN!!!!!!!

Comment: Ahahahahahahahaha!

Comment: Niiiiiiiicccceee....

Answer (score 9):

Holy **Crap** this scared me.  Wake up this morning, drudge through things, go into Meta, see this and think "Oh crap, I didn't cover things up well enough..."

But yea, what Jeff said.  That's definitely the secret.  Weird I missed this the first go-around months back.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe there are more links from outside the stackoverflow domain pointing to their profiles?

Answer (score 3):

This has been [mentioned before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30247/unusual-google-sitelinks-for-superuser), but it was about Super User.

Although [Jeff mentions there](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30247/unusual-google-sitelinks-for-superuser/30307#30307) that it should be fixed.

Something must have brought this back...

Answer (score 3):

Now it's [two](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13302/marc-s) [other](https://stackoverflow.com/users/29407/darin-dimitrov) users...

May be there should be more sections for Google's sake. May be a podcast section (is it defunct?), or a more prominently linked http://jobs.stackoverflow.com, or may be a link to the 
 [canonical question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/84556/whats-your-favorite-programmer-cartoon) on SO. Also Meta is suspiciously absent from there.

Comment: ok, I blocked those as well. Eventually it will fill up with non-user links.. hopefully.. sigh.. my /users/{id}/name block list is enormous now on every trilogy site, you'd think Google would figure this out eventually.