# Google Search for Stack Overflow Careers includes user profiles as Sitelevel links

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

The [following Google search](http://www.google.com/#hl=en&cp=14&gs_id=1f&xhr=t&q=Stackoverflow+careers&qe=U3RhY2tvdmVyZmxvdyA&qesig=rxO1hQxymSNopmp79DZHnQ&pkc=AFgZ2tmLe7YDkoAEbZthMn4Ej48avqqeO6wobquWdb5dmvBioOmEQBT1ZR4b7TjjCGgab067IV-n7McOMlSdsPdhmGDH3zkrEw&pf=p&sclient=psy&source=hp&pbx=1&oq=Stackoverflow+&aq=0&aqi=g5&aql=&gs_sm=&gs_upl=&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.&fp=7854c883595a039e&biw=1920&bih=995)

> `StackOverflow Careers`

produces two user profiles as site level links, `Daniel Huckstep`, and `Adam Varga`:

[image]

If I instead search for

> `Stack Overflow Careers` (note the space)

I get `Marcus WhyBrow` and `Matthew Abbott` as site level links:

[image]

This appears to be the same problem as [is described here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35497/tom-ritter-ngu-soon-hui-what-is-your-secret), just with a different site.

Also appears to be happening when Googling `Apple.Stackexchange` (Dori's name comes up first).

Answer (score 1):

This looks like it has been fixed.